# defaultdict not recognising 2 digit numbers in python

Tags: python

My code should output scores from a game and sort them alphabetically according to each player's name with the highest score of each player, only taking this from the last 3 scores of the player.

It works fine until the score is 10, which is the highest you can score in the game. I figured that it is something to do with the score being two digits instead of one digit.

```
 def alpha():
    d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.deque(maxlen=3))
    with open("scores.txt" as f:
        for line in f:
            player,score = line.strip().split(":")
            d[player].append(score)
        for k in sorted(d):
            values = max(d[k])
            print(k + " " + " ".join(map(str, values)))
```

Does anyone know what is causing the problem?
I am using python 3.3.2.

Here is my text file:

```
Aaron:1
Ronnie:10
Ronnie:2
Ronnie:4
Aaron:5
Vick:6
Vick:9
Vick:2
Andy:5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing string scores instead of integer ones, and hence, they will be compared as strings. Since string comparison is lexicographic, `"10" < "9"` is `True` and so is `"10" < "2"` and so on, and hence your code fails for 2 digits because the comparison is not right.

To correct this, convert the scores to integers and replace this line

```
d[player].append(score)
```

with this:

```
d[player].append(int(score))
```